# How can I append a username to my ../profile/<username> URL so each user has a unique page. -MEAN -Jade

Tags: javascript, url, pug, profile, mean

I'm in charge of setting up profile pages for each user. I have set up a way to route through to "../profile/:username", but I cannot figure out how to actually render a unique page for each user.

Here is my get from index.js

```
router.get('/profile/:userName', function (req, res) {
  //find user object from database
  var userName = req.params.userName;
  var userObject = userlistdb.find({ username: userName });
  //route through to the user's unique profile page
  res.render('profile/' + userObject.username, { ObjectId: userObject._id});});
```

My profile.jade is pretty abysmal so I won't bother sharing.

Our app is connected to a remote Mongo database and as far as I can tell it's being called correctly. When I route through to a user page from our db, I get the error "Failed to lookup view "profile/undefined" in views directory". Because there is no /profile/[username].jade file for any user this isn't working.

How can I get around this issue? Do I need to create a new jade file for each user?

Thanks

Comment: Because I mostly fixed it on my own, I'll post my fix here for other poor souls. I just removed the "+ userObject.username" from my render call because that view didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render file `profile/:userId` as it doesn't exist, so

```
res.render('profile/' + userObject.username)
```

gonna throw exception, but what you can do is render `profile_page` for a specific user.

- use callback on database calls,
- create 2-3 views(`error.jade, profile_not_found.jade, profile_page.jade`)

And router should look like

```
router.get('/profile/:userName', function (req, res) {
    //find user object from database
    var userName = req.params.userName;

    //findOne will return single user instance
    userlistdb.findOne({username: userName}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            //render some error page 
            //pass error, populate view, or just send InternalServerError(500)
            res.render('error', {err: err}); 
        } else if (!user){
            //render 404 or more specific page
            //pass not found username
            res.render('profile_not_found', {username: username}); 
        } else {
            //render user page
            //route through to the user's unique profile page
            res.render('profile_page', {user: user}); //pass user, populate view
        }
    });
});
```